# MS Access : Count of more than One specific values in one row

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013, correlated-subquery

I have a Table in MS Access database (Office 2013):

```
Table1
ID  ACC_YEAR    PROGRESS
1   2008-09     IP
2   2008-09     IP
3   2008-09     C
4   2009-10     IP
```

"ACC_YEAR" is a text field and "PROGRESS" field may have four possible values: IP / C / NS / UCS.

Now I want to have a YEAR wise & PROGRESS wise count report like this:

```
ACC_YEAR    IP     C     NS     UCS   PROGRESS_TOTAL
2008-09     2      1     0      0     3
2009-10     2      1     0      0     3
```

Anyone please help to construct the SQL for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: GROUP BY, count(case ...)

Answer (score 2):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select acc_year,
       sum(iif(Progress = "IP", 1, 0)) as IP,
       sum(iif(Progress = "C", 1, 0)) as C,
       sum(iif(Progress = "NS", 1, 0)) as NS,
       sum(iif(Progress = "UCS", 1, 0)) as UCS,
       count(*)
from table
group by acc_year
order by acc_year;
```